# Convert object to formatted readable text

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a variable `data` that looks like:

```
{"Name":"Username","Crew":"None","Wealth":"Billionaire","Rank":"Respectable Hitman","Status":"Alive ( Online )","Messages sent":"3","Messages received":"1"}
```

I want to convert this object so that it reads

```
Name: Username
Crew: None
Wealth: Billionaire
Rank: Respectable Hitman
Status: Alive ( Online )
Messages sent: 3
Messages received: 1
```

What's the best way to convert this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the object with for?
EDIT: added hasOwnProperty to make sure it doesn't get other unwanted values

```js
var obj = {"Name":"Username","Crew":"None","Wealth":"Billionaire","Rank":"Respectable Hitman","Status":"Alive ( Online )","Messages sent":"3","Messages received":"1"}

let str = '';  
for (let i in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    str = str + `${i}:  ${obj[i]}\n`;
  }
}

console.log(str)
```

Comment: when using a for..in loop you should always perform a check to make sure the property `i` is actually an own property of `obj`

Comment: @snek: Depends on the case. If a property somewhere up an object’s prototype is enumerable, it might be intended for inclusion in whatever loop, or it might not.

Comment: `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, i)` if you want to do that, though, so it doesn’t break when the input has a property called “hasOwnProperty”.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. Works just like I needed it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 8):

The standard library and template literals can help out nicely here:

```js
var data = { "Name": "Username", "Crew": "None", "Wealth": "Billionaire", "Rank": "Respectable Hitman", "Status": "Alive ( Online )", "Messages sent": "3", "Messages received": "1" };

var text = Object.entries(data)
  .map(([name, value]) => `${name}: ${value}`)
  .join('\n');

console.log(text)
```

Comment: Why not just `.map(a => a[0] + ': ' + a[1])`?

Comment: @Nick To address two separate parts here: I choose to explicitly name the variables to help with readability (we aren't exactly pressed for line space in this example). I choose template literals because they're designed for the task and IMO much easier to read.

Comment: @snek that makes sense. Thanks.